# validate userId given by okta

Tags: node.js, okta

I have an app which consists of frontend server and a backend server.
front end server connect to corporate OKTA mechanism so that user logins through their corporate ids into my app.

After this step, frontend server connects with some backend work at backkend server (node js). Their it passes in the request body the user id so that we can finally log that the below processing is happening due to user X.

Now suppose user A logs into the app . Now during the APi call to backend server, he can modify the arguments being passed to the api  and somehow change the userID.

Is there some way by which backend server validate that userID is not compromised ?

Regards

Comment: The login process should have given you some kind of access_token. The backend should use that to figure out who's currently logged in, not a user_id

Answer (score 0):

If your front-end app uses OIDC to log a user in, then you should be able to get back an id_token, which has user identity in it. You can pass this token to your back end app for API calls. This approach is not ideal though, as your backend will still have issues with trust, as it does not know if the token presented by the front-end app is a legitimate one and not stolen.

Other way is to harness traditional authorization_code flow (again, assuming you can do OIDC with you company's identity provider). There your back-end would retrieve the tokens for you directly from authorization server and can get a user's identity from it. Based on that it can then create a session and embed user info into it. It's a bullet proof approach lacking trust issues from above.